# How do I copy data to buffer in eBPF?

Tags: c, ebpf, bpf, xdp-bpf

I'm wanting to store the packets' payload to my custom buffer in eBPF & XDP hook. But I can't pass the verifier. I learned others' code found no difference.

In the code, I checked the length of payload should be less than MTU, which is 1500 in my code. The buffer size is (1<<20), much larger than MTU.

Here is my code in `.kern` :

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE (1<<20)
#define MTU 1500

struct my_buffer {
    __u32 len;
    char buf[BUFFER_SIZE + 5];
};
struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") map_my_buffer = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY,
    .key_size = sizeof(unsigned int),
    .value_size = sizeof(struct my_buffer),
    .max_entries = 1,
};


SEC("WriteBuffer")
int WriteBuffer_main(struct xdp_md *ctx) {
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
    char *payload = data + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct udphdr);
    if (payload >= data_end) return XDP_PASS;

    unsigned int zero = 0;
    struct my_buffer *fd = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&map_my_buffer, &zero);
    if (!fd) return XDP_PASS; // can't find the context...

    __u32 data_len = data_end - (void *)payload;
    if (data_len > MTU) return XDP_PASS;

    for (__u32 i = 0; i < MTU && payload + i + 1 <= data_end; i++) {
        fd -> buf[i] = payload[i];
    }

    return XDP_DROP;
}
```

The error message is: It tells there is an error when accessing packet's payload, but I did the boundary check...

```
67: (bf) r2 = r5
68: (57) r2 &= 4064
69: (0f) r9 += r2
70: (bf) r5 = r2
71: (71) r1 = *(u8 *)(r4 -16)
72: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -16) = r1
73: (71) r1 = *(u8 *)(r4 -15)
invalid access to packet, off=120 size=1, R4(id=0,off=135,r=120)
R4 offset is outside of the packet
processed 60 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 5 peak_states 5 mark_read 4
```

I'm really confused, hope someone can help out, Thanks!

**Update**: I followed the guide from pchaigno, and changed the loop to this:

```
for (__u32 i = 0; i <= MTU && i < data_len && payload + i + 1 <= data_end; ++i) {
    fd -> buf[i] = payload[i];
}
```

Then passed the verifier... I think it's unreasonable cause there are redundancy in these three conditions...

Comment: I don't think that boundary check on MTU is enough for the verifier. Try to do the boundary on `i` instead, inside the loop. We would need the full verifier output to confirm that's the issue.

Comment: Really thanks, I edited my loop and passed the verifier, but it's still confusing to me...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in those lines:

```c
for (__u32 i = 0; i < MTU && payload + i + 1 <= data_end; i++) {
    fd -> buf[i] = payload[i];
}
```

This is a common problem: **the compiler probably[1] computed and stored `payload + i + 1` and `payload[i]` in two different registers**.

Let's say the first is in R5 and the second in R6. When the compiler compared R5 to `data_end`, it understands that there's a new upper bound `data_end` for R5, but it's not smart enough to understand what that means for `i`. So when it then computes R6, it can't infer any upper bound for that new register.

Adding a bounds check on `i` solves it. The bounds check on `payload + i + 1` may be unnecessary.

[1] - We would need the full verifier logs to confirm.